# Limit of $\lim_{n\to\infty} n-ne\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$?

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I calculate

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty} n-ne\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

Edit: changed it to correct question with $1-1/n$

Comment: Write it as $n(1-e(1+1/n)^n)$, use [that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n)^n=e$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_limits#Notable_special_limits). Therefore $1-e(1+1/n)^n\to1-e^2<0$. Finally, since $n\to\infty$, then the given limit tends to $-\infty$.

Comment: For the new one you can write it as $\frac{1-e^{\frac{\ln(1-1/n)}{1/n}+1}}{1/n}$. Compute a few terms of the series expansion (in powers of $1/n$) of $\frac{\ln(1-1/n)}{1/n}+1$ in powers of $1/n$ to get $-1/(2 n) - 1/(3 n^2)+...$. Then compose with the series of $e^x$ to get the initial terms of the series (in powers of $1/n$) of the original expression $1/2 + 5/(24 n)+...$. Therefore, the limit is $1/2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
n-ne\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n
&= n-nee^{n\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)} \\
&= n-nee^{\left(-1-\frac{1}{2n}+O(\frac{1}{n^2})\right)} \\
&= n-n\left(1-\frac{1}{2n}+O(\frac{1}{n^2})\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}+O(\frac{1}{n})
\end{align}
then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n-ne\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=\color{blue}{\frac12}$$

Comment: Hah :) . . . . .

Comment: Only bright hearts are trusted.